# Factorization of permutations into two factors with fixed number of cycles, plus a placement condition

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

I have asked this question in MathOverflow, but it received no answers, so I am posting it here.

In my recent work I have been led to consider the following type of permutation factorizations.

Let $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ be two fixed permutations, with disjoint support, i.e. $\pi_1$ acts on $\{1,...,n\}$ and $\pi_2$ acts on $\{n+1,...,n+m\}$.

Find all pairs $(\tau_1,\tau_2)$, such that
$\pi_1\pi_2=\tau_1\tau_2$, with the condition that every cycle of the factors $\tau_1,\tau_2$ has exactly one element in $\{1,...,n\}$.

Notice that the last condition implies that $\ell(\tau_1)=\ell(\tau_2)=n$.

For example, $ (123)(45678)=(1 5)(2 4)(3 8 7 6)\cdot (1 4)(2 6 8)(3 5 7)$ is a case with $n=3$, $m=5$.

I just want to know if anyone has seen a similar problem before. If this is really a new problem, does anyone have a suggestion for naming these things?